# Can a Fortran function return multiple variables?

Tags: fortran

In the example function below how can one tell whether `a`, `b` or `c` are input or output values, other than from the context?

Also, if `example()` is called is a value assigned to `c` outside the scope of `example()`?

```
function example(a, b, c)
   real*8 a, b, c
   c = a + b
   example = c
end function example
```

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, If I call example(a, b, c) after assigning a = 1 and b = 2 then I see that c is assigned c = 3 *and* example() also returns 3. What is going on with c? Should I think of it like a pointer in C/C++? Please edit, if you like!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, how would returning an array of values work?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, that's not quite what I thought you were saying. I should have asked, "how would returning an array of variables work?" Where variables could be dimensioned arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortran has the possibility to specify intent attribute:

> The INTENT attribute specifies the intended use of a dummy argument. An INTENT (IN) dummy argument is suitable for receiving data from the invoking scoping unit, an INTENT (OUT) dummy argument is suitable for returning data to the invoking scoping unit, and an INTENT (INOUT) dummy argument is suitable for use both to receive data from and to return data to the invoking scoping unit.

Furthermore one can specify a result attribute or give the function a type,
So one could write:

```
double precision function example(a, b, c)
   implicit none
   double precision, intent(in) :: a, b
   double precision, intent(out) :: c
   c = a + b
   example = c
end function example
```

or

```
function example(a, b, c) result(res)
   implicit none
   double precision, intent(in) :: a, b
   double precision, intent(out) :: c
   double precision :: res
   c = a + b
   res = c
end function example
```

Note: I also added the "implicit none" and replaced the real*8 by double precision.

Comment: Yes! intent() is what will help me clarify this. Thanks, I'm new to fortran and I've inherited some *really* old code.

Comment: It is considered by some (maybe by many) to be bad practice to write functions with side-effects.  If you need more than one value returned, use a subroutine.

Comment: Yes, I think I agree. This sort of thing makes it really difficult to track what is going on.

Comment: @albert, I like this answer, but you should fix the second example by enclosing the function def with and END, right?

Comment: I prefer the second form because I can rename the function name without having to rename the return value assignment.

Answer (score 3):

You have an answer which talks about *intents* for arguments.  These provide valuable hints to the programmer (as a form of documentation) and compiler as to how the arguments are used.  These intents give an idea of the restrictions on an argument and apply to procedures (subroutines as well as functions) more widely.

However, some dummy arguments may even not be allowed to be given an intent.  Further, an intent specification doesn't mean that the argument is used in that way (intent(in) arguments needn't be referenced; intent(inout) variables needn't be modified; intent(out) arguments needn't be defined).

Ultimately you will have to look at the function's behaviour.

Given the function of the question

```
function example(a, b, c)
   real*8 a, b, c
   c = a + b
   example = c
end function example
```

we can consider `a` and `b` to be "inputs" and they must be defined when the function is entered and their values are used in evaluating the function result.  The function result is called `example` but there is a side-effect of modifying `c`, an "output".  Its value on entering the function isn't needed, and it needn't even be defined.

Now, this being Fortran, there is a subtlety to note.  You ask

> is a value assigned to c outside the scope of `example`?

and the answer is, *possibly*.

If `example` were a subroutine then yes, the actual argument matching `c` would have a value defined after the subroutine call.  With `example` a function, then maybe not.

Consider:

```
implicit none
real*8 a, b, c, d
real*8 example  ! Really you should be using an explicit interface

a = 1.
b = 2.
c = 0.
d = 0.

print*, example(a,b,c)
print*, c

if (.false..and.example(a,b,d)>0) print*

end program
```

then although the value of `c` is modified by this function reference, the variable `d` actually becomes undefined!<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>  By "undefined" I mean that it doesn't have a value that you can reliably query or use.  Because Fortran allows a compiler to short-circuit the evaluation of the function but doesn't it require it, it says that the value becomes undefined.  You can't rely on side effects from a function if you can't be sure that the function is used.

Comment: Thank you for this additional explanation. I have been tasked with going through a set of *Fortran* ;) programs, cleaning them up and generating documentation so that they can be incorporated into a larger C++ backend. Intent declaration is sufficient for my needs, but I will heed your advice for any future Fortran functions/subroutines I write!

Comment: Putting intents into a procedure is indeed one of the greatest pieces of documentation effort you can make (I don't want my answer to suggest they aren't important).  However, please do be aware that there are a lot of subtle considerations.  One can't just look and say "I set the value but don't need it before: intent(out)", or "I need the value, so it must be intent(in) or intent(inout)".  That's off-topic for you current question, however.

Comment: can you recommend an online resource describing intent declarations?

Comment: Searching questions here will give the basics and beyond.  There are some of the gotchas to be seen here (edge cases and such), but if think there's some information missing, please ask.

Comment: Just a subtlety here.  The value of `d` may or may not be defined.  The Fortran standard does not enforce short circuiting of logical expressions.  While .false. is a constant and a compiler will likely remove the if-stmt as dead code, the Fortran standard does permit the evaluation of example(a,b,d).

Comment: @evets, precisely because the Fortran standard doesn't enforce or disallow short-circuiting, the value of `d` is certainly undefined (F2018 19.6.6 (2)).  `example` may be evaluated but it needn't be: so any side effects cannot be relied upon.

Comment: @evets, I appreciate that my meaning may be unclear so I've edited the answer.

Comment: This is a neat answer. +1

Comment: @francescalus, I've read enough of your replies to know you understand Fortran and short circuting.  My comment was meant more for the OP to ensure that s/he understood that Fortran does not require short circuiting.

Comment: @evets, thanks for clarifying.  I'm happy to have comments which point out errors or parts which are unclear (or may be phrased in a way that don't naturally get understood they way I intended).  Hopefully my edit after your prompt was a net improvement.